# can't Resolve rxjs

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

Failed to compile.

> ./src/app/hero.service.ts Module not found:  Error: Can't resolve
>   'rxjs/Observable/of' in 'C:\Users\Admin\angular\myheroes\src\app'
>
> ```
> @ ./src/app/hero.service.ts 13:11-40 
> @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 
> @ ./src/main.ts 
> @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
> ```

my code for hero.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { of } from 'rxjs/Observable/of';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

   constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]>

  {
    // todo: send the message _after_fetching the heroes
    this.messageService.add('HeroService: fetched heroes');
    return of (HEROES);
  }
}
```

Comment: try this `import  'rxjs/Observable/of';`

Comment: The import is `import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';`

Comment: lower case `observable` instead of `O`

Comment: Thank you for help, it works

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually you will have a file in your project called something like `rxjs-operators.ts` which imports the parts of `rxjs` that you need.  You should add this line to that file:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

Also take out this line:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

Alternatively, import it into your module directly, see if it works.

Comment: I'm sure your edit was with good intentions @Delian, but that line directly referenced the incorrect line from the original question, which needed to be removed. Hence I left it identical :)

Comment: This also seems to be the exact opposite of what should be suggested.  RxJS 5.5.2 and version 5 of Angular strongly suggests getting away from importing operators this way.

Answer (score 61):

I got this error because of an older version of rxjs and Angular 6 needs the latest version of rxjs.

This command installs the latest version that is compatible with Angular 6.

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation why you think this will solve the OPs problem.

Comment: Worked me as well!

Comment: I had problems with a dependency looking for an rxjs component, and this solution worked for me :)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 21):

As Aravind has pointed out in his comments, case is important here.  Instead of

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/Observable/of';
```

try (unsure the version)...

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';  // note the lower-cased 'o' on 'observable'
```

or when version is > 6.x

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

Based on Alexander Kim's comment, I must urge folks to go read the [documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators), and get clear around the distinction between the 2 major operator types: creator, and everything else (mostly trans-formative).

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50219421/2250792).

[Try RxJS now!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-by-example)  (opens new stackblitz session with RxJS library loaded)

Comment: This is outdated answer.

Answer (score 11):

For those of you who are alive as of July 13th, the correct way for importing the of module is as follows:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
```

I am pretty sure because of the improper naming conventions accessing a capital O and a lower case o folder, they included it in a more all encompassing manner.

Note: THIS IS THE BLEEDING EDGE. ;)

Comment: It still says "Property 'from' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.ts(2339)"

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem and I fixed the problem like follows...

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

Where is used:

```
Observable.of(something)
```

Note: Important to take a look always in [npm rxjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs), there you can find the documentation for the current version

Answer (score 3):

I have the same error for both angular/core and rxjs.
This is the way I fix the issue, by explicitly saying to the compiler where to find the library :

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "paths": { 
    "@angular/*": ["../../node_modules/@angular/*"],
    "rxjs/*": ["../../node_modules/rxjs/*"]
  },
}
```

Comment: where do you mention this? WHich file?

Comment: you should try your config file such as tsconfig.json

Answer (score 2):

The answers on this question are contradictory, the question is good, but there is no answer that is really helping.

It all has to do with the change of API from Rxjs since version 6.0

The answers here are confusing because of the different versions of RxJs, that is the problem. An answer starting or ending with: "This works for me" is useless, because that is not an answer, that is an example how it might work, but you never have the full story, so it is useless because it does not explain anything.

It is all very well explained here:
https://academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/
If you have 12 minutes, it is also well explained in this Youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9fdpGthrXA

I know that external links are not appreciated in StackOverflow, and with good reason, and although it is not very much to know, it is quite some explanation for a short and helpful answer.

So in short, resuming, the problem has to do with differences between the Rxjs API before version 6.0 and since RxJs 6.0
If you want to keep the pre-6.0 code unchanged, you should install rxjs-compat, it is not very bad

Better is to change the code, and have an up to date and ready for the future.

Comment: last year, I have solved my problems by answers which are given to this question.

Comment: Which answer? There are a few contradicting each other.

Comment: So there was one answer helpful, but there were 8 more, contradicting that one. Do you think that is helpful? That that answer worked for you is good luck. Because you did not mention your RxJs version or Angular version, and the answer is only applicable for RxJs past version 6, but it does not mention that. Others are about pre RxJs 6 and also do not mention that.  So that is what I see as lack of quality in answering. In this way, the question and the answers are helping noone. It is just a confusing mess. StackOverflow should improve this.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now I am understand what you mean to say.

Answer (score 2):

Angular 7 and RxJS 6+

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { tap, map, switchMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators'
```

All operators are now in `rxjs/operators`.

Answer (score 2):

The next steps work for me.

1) Import **of** operator

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'; 
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

2) Install **rxjs-compat** package

```
$ npm i --save rxjs-compat
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

import { Hero } from './hero';

import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
```

Always make sure that order of referencing the files should be in a correct order.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got the error because of the path of rxjs in **webpack.config.js**.

I created the project under C drive with **angular-cli** and I used `ng eject` to eject the project and generate the **webpack.config.js**.

Actually **angular-cli** inject an absolute path for rxjs like below:

```
"alias": {
      "rxjs/observable/of": "C:\\my_project_directory\\node_modules\\rxjs\\_esm5\\observable\\of.js"

...}
```

After manually correcting it to a relative path

```
"alias": {
      "rxjs/observable/of": "rxjs\\_esm5\\observable\\of.js"

.. }
```

It started working.

Answer (score 0):

The next steps work for me.

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
```