# How to get "Observable.of([]);" to work?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

What is the correct expression and import for `Observable.of([]);`.

`import { of } from 'rxjs';` does not work for me.

Comment: You just need to import **Observable**

Comment: can you try this   import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

Comment: `import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of'` does not work in RxJS 6

Comment: `import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';` is the same problem

Comment: Use `of(...)` instead of `Observable.of(...)`

Comment: This  question is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568388/observable-of-is-not-a-function because OP is using RxJS 6 and what was mentioned in the referenced question won't work as it's already deprecated.

Comment: It only works w/the trailing slash for me: `import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs/';`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since RxJS 6 you should import all "creation" observables directly from `'rxjs'` (assuming you have [path maps](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#build-and-treeshaking) set when bundling your app).

More detailed explanation: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#import-paths

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

of(1).subscribe(console.log);
```

See demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-e3lxkb?file=index.ts

Comment: FYI... Link is broke.  Also, came here hunting for comparison between the operator and the creator of `of`

Answer (score -1):

No need to use Observable.of(T)
Instead you can use the below syntax in the rxjs 6.3.3

```
return new Observable<AppUser>();
```