# Difference between `of` operator and `Observable.of`

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

So what is the difference between `of` operator and `Observable.of` and what is the recommended way to create an observable?

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
const obs$ = Observable.of(3);
```

or

```
import { of as observableOf } from 'rxjs';
const obs$ = observableOf(3);
```

Comment: What is the relation between Operator and Observable?

Comment: @RameshRajendran I'm asking the difference between Observable.of and 'of' not between Observable and of operator

Comment: If you import `Observable`, you can use all global operators right away. Your second snippet requires modification of `import` every time you need to use another operator. IIRC, before RxJS 6 it was recommended way because tree shaking was broken, but in 6+ you can do what you did in the first snippet. Also, second form is more "functional", as you can compose it using `pipe` operator, but first form is closer to JS way.

Comment: @alx _" but in 6+ you can do what you did in the first snippet. "_ No, you can't. _" first form is closer to JS way"_ Why not the second one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50218784/rxjs-6-how-to-get-observable-of-to-work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second way is the preferred way, and going forward (from rxjs v7) the only way. Currenly in v6 you can still use the first by including the rxjs-compat package, but writing new code, you should stick to the last method mentioned.